# NamedPipeClientStream with .NET Framework 3.0 doesn't work

Tags: c#, wpf, named-pipes, .net-framework-version

I need to write a WPF app or a windows service with the .NET Framework 3.0. 
This app needs to use the NamedPipeClientStream but I'm not able to understand if this class is supported on .NET Framework 3.0. 
I looked for some Microsoft documentation but I didn't find anything. 
VS suggests me to import the System.Core.dll to resolve the dependency, but it take this dependency from the .NET Framework 4.6 folder.
My PC (Windows 10) has already .NET Framework 3.5 installed and the documentation says that it provide the support already for .NET Framework 2.0/3.0.

This app will run on Windows XP and I haven't the possibility to install other frameworks or make massive changes to the OS.

Answer (score 0):

See the [Microsoft documentation for NamedPipeClientStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.pipes.namedpipeclientstream?view=netframework-4.8) here.

At the bottom of the page, the relevant frameworks are listed.  It looks like this class is only available in v3.5 and above.